# Regex for a single string in a sentence?

Tags: python-3.x

How do I only use `python` from `<:python:456490778085163011>`

Comment: you don't need regex for this. hint: try with `split`

Answer (score 1):

Try this without using `re`.

```
'<:python:456490778085163011>'.split(':')[1]
```

Using `re`

```
def printWord(txt):
    resp = re.match('^<:(?P<word>\w*):\d+>\w*$', txt)
    if resp:
        print(resp.group('word'))

printWord('<:python:456490778085163011>')
printWord('<:java:4564907324085163011>')
printWord('<:anyword:456490778085163011>')
```

Hope it will help!

Comment: Not the specific word python but for any word. How can I do that?

Comment: I tried something like `(?!<::\d+>)\w+` but it's not good enough.

Comment: are they have `:` around the word, If yes then it will work for all cases.